# Display Video Thumbnail in Bigger Size

Tags: java, android

is there any way to display the thumbnail from the given path in bigger size than the "MINI_KIND" offers?

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

        if (first)
            imageView.setImageResource(position);
        else
            imageView.setImageBitmap(thumb);
```

[The size that i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSHMp.png)
and 
[the size that i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR8Mj.png)

Answer (score -1):

what about using `Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND`? [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html#MICRO_KIND) is the api to look for